# How can I change (or failing that delete) a Kickstarter vanity URL?

Tags: kickstarter

When I signed up for Kickstarter I did so to back a project on behalf of my son who didn't have a credit card. At the time the plan was for him to take on the account so we created a vanity URL in his name.

However, I have since taken over the account to I can back stuff on my own account and I'd like to change the vanity URL to something more "me".

I don't see an option to change - or even delete - this on the profile page.

Is there a way to change the URL or failing that remove it so I can create a new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to change your Vanity URL after setting it the first time.

---

[image: Kickstarter Vanity URL]

Comment: Not sure how I missed that. Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

Chris - however it is pretty easy to change the email associated with your KS account. So, assuming you are fine not keeping htethe backer history you have on the account you opened first, you could change the email associated with that account to either your son's email, or another email.  Then you can open a new account tied to your preferred email.

Any backer history associated with the original account, will remain with that account (that is now tied to your son's or alternate email), but you could now choose a new vanity url.

Both accounts can be linked to the same Amazon account.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get it changed.
You can't change it yourself, but you can ask KickStarter support to change it for you

> **Can I reset my vanity URL?**
>
> If you made a mistake when entering your vanity URL, or would like to choose something different, you can request a vanity URL reset by contacting our Support team and they’ll be happy to help.

Source: [What is a vanity URL](https://help.kickstarter.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005127014-What-is-a-vanity-URL-)